# How can I modify this regex to allow a dot (.) in the username of an email

Tags: regex

I'm working on an Angular application and I'm trying to modify a regex so that it will validate the email, but at the same time allow for a dot/period (.) in the username.

Here's what I have so far:

```
/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
```

and here's the email address I'm using to test:

```
dg.-_application_support@dsd.com
```

I haven't spent a lot of time with regular expressions, so I'm completely confused.

Comment: Change the first quantifier to `[.-]+` https://regex101.com/r/VG2mwa/1

Comment: `[\.-]?` matches only one character (either `.` or `-`) while you have two. Change it to `[\.-]*`.

Comment: Each `([\.-]?\w+)*` must be `([.-]+\w+)*`

Comment: Why can’t you simply use the browser’s email type input field? Why do you need to come up with your own rules for valid addresses? I’m pretty certain you’re missing a lot more valid addresses with this.

Comment: That was it fourth bird, thank you!

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
^\w+([\.-]\w*?)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+
```

The problem was the + sign after the second \w, it takes one or zero, you had 2. So replacing it with *? will take zero or more, lazy (only as needed not more)

Comment: The `([\.-]\w*?)*` is a straight road to [catastrophic backtracking](https://regex101.com/r/ehp13I/1).